# How to show custom option in checkout page in the view detais in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, onepage-checkout

I'm developing a custom module in magento 2. I need to show  the custom options in checkout page which file i edit and show there custom option in magento 2

anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin and enable template path hints from `Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug->Enable template path hint for frontend` set to `YES`.

Then you can see file path on order page and edit or override that according to your requirement.